# PrimeNg confirmDialog make changes on my navbar

Tags: html, css, angular, navbar, primeng

My navbar works really well and it is fully responsible, but when I open confirm dialog in background my navbar width goes to `800px` even if screen has `1480px` making an empty space on the right side like you can notice on the screen.

[image: cut off navbar]

I really don't have idea how to fix it, this is my navbar:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" routerLink="">frontend</a>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link menu-item dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Vehicles</a>
        <div class=" dropdown dropdown-menu">
          <a class="dropdown-item menu-item" routerLink="/topic"> Vehicles list </a>
          <a class="dropdown-item menu-item" routerLink="/add-topic"> Add vehicle </a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

I use default confirm dialog from primeNg without any changes:
[confirm dialog](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/confirmdialog)

Maybe I could somehow make additional css to navbar to make position allways on 100% of screen? Any ideas how could I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using bootstrap navbar and primeng so some css are getting conflict. If you write below css in style.css so navbar working normal.

```
.ui-overflow-hidden {
    position: unset !important;
}
```

Comment: @degath Glad to help you.